# Digital signature of document java

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

I have been searching for this in web and java tutorials.But i have no clarification about how to generate a digital signature for a document. This is explained in java tutorial, but what i exactly want is

1. user comes with a file and a secret key which is a **String**.
2. using that secret key, file is digitally signed.
3. the corresponding public key, and the sign is published with that document.

So, how to convert the given *String* private key to do this. While trying the examples given in java tutorials, and web (with some variation of putting bytes from string instead of files) i got exceptions like

```
Caught: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: IOException : Detect premature EOF
```

Comment: What kind of `String` is on your mind? A custom one chosen so that a human can remember it easily? Or just a `String` to transport the data? The latter can be done by e.g. bas64 encoding an actual private key.

Comment: Human friendly string

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you're out of luck. At least if you want an interoperable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find a sample because the string is not a private key of the appropriate key pair (yet I can imagine that *some* asymmetric keys can look like a text string).

Keypairs are generated. If you control both signer and verifier, it's theoretically possible to generate a keypair using the string as a seed for randomizer, thus getting repeatable randomization results on both signer and verifier side, but security of this approach is questionable.

I must admit that your idea to sign using text strings is appealing, but unfortunately not generally possible.